# Update JavaScript variables in background using PHP + jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a part of the code in a 'process.php' file:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> percYes = ".$yes."</script>"
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> percNo = ".$no."</script>"
```

This 'process.php' file runs in the background (using jQuery/ajax) when the user clicks a butto. The 'echoed' html above replaces the contents of a div. So essentially what I'm trying to do is update some Javascript variables using a background php call, the above solution does not seem to work though, i.e. the script is not being ran once it is placed in the div.

A bonus problem involves using these updated Javascript variables to update a graph. I have a workng javascript graphing function, but the problem is getting the new graph to replace the old one (or just update it, if that's possible).

Thanks.

Comment: what function are you using to make the ajax call. To parse the data as script , I guess $.load needs to be used and not $.ajax.

Comment: I really don't know too much about this stuff, but I'm using `xmlhttp.open()` and `xmlhttp.send()`. I'll have a look into $.load. EDIT: Wow, $.load looks perfect.

Comment: There is also jQuery's [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to just load a script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is update some JS vars, you may be better off having your process.php file returning a json string:

```
$array = ('percYes' => $yes, 'percNo' => $no);
echo json_encode($array);
```

This will give you a json string that can be evaluated and used in a callback for your JS ajax call.

So if you have a var 'percYes' and 'percNo' in an accessible scope, your callback could look something like this:

```
function(jsonstr) {
  obj = eval(jsonstr);
  percYes = obj.percYes;
  percNo  = obj.percNo;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds great! So when I want to update the js variables I call function(jsonstr)?